# pycharm not allowing selection on virtualenv interpreter on Windows

Tags: pycharm, virtualenv

Following the docs (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html) on how to use an existing virtualenv interpreter for pycharm IDE, I see

[image]

(notice that the bin folder has been clicked and indicates empty) despite the fact that I can confirm that the interpreter is in fact there and the dir. is no empty via commandline (using cygwin)

```
➜  datagov_example ls bin
activate      activate.fish     easy_install      pip   pip2.7  python2    python-config
activate.csh  activate_this.py  easy_install-2.7  pip2  python  python2.7  wheel
```

Does anyone know what is going on here and how to fix it?